# How can I remove the space between text and div inside?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space between texts and div inside. There's a picture of what I mean under space between text and div.

[image]

That space is really annoying. There is the style sheet and html:

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(204, 33, 33);
}

p {
  margin-inline: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(204, 33, 33);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: remove your margin.

Or give your ```<p>``` a ```margin-top``` and ```margin-bottom``` of 0. I'm not sure which look you're trying to achieve.

Comment: And use the Inspector to see whether you're inheriting any padding on the div, too.

Comment: You might need to add div font-size:0 + some font size to p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `p` to `span`
and alter CSS:

```
div {
       ...
       ...
       padding: 10px;
}

span {
      margin: 10px 0;
      ...
      ...
}
```

Or increase the div padding and remove span's margin, depending on the resulting UI that you need

Comment: Thanks! It's working.

Answer (score 1):

`margin-inline: 10px;` this cause the issue you were facing, remove that and you get what you want.

```css
div {
    display: inline-flex;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 2px solid rgb(204, 33, 33);
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(204, 33, 33);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```